# Make an action when button clicked only if checkbox is marked

Tags: java, android, button, checkbox

I have **a button** and **a checkbox**. How can I do if the user check the box, it make one action (like a toast) and if the box is not checked another toast.
I mean:

```
If the box is checked and I click the button:
'The box was checked'
If the box is not checked and I click the button
'The box was not checked'
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: Please refer to my answer below and let me know if it is exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Inside button listener place if statement to check if checkbox is checked. If checked do something else don't do.

A simple algorithm would be:

```
if(checkbox is checked){
display toast saying is checked
}else{
display toast saying is not checked
}
```

And put this inside your **onClickListener** of **button**

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation:

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
         if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
             // display toast1
         }
         else {
             // display toast2
         }
     }
 });
```

Is that what you're looking for?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: No absolutely not the answer

Comment: Clever, now it is :-)

Comment: I think the OP wants you to type in `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The box was checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` also.I mean he didn't try anything before asking this question i guess.